# Zend Validation - Specify multiple ways to validate a request - depending on whats in the request

Tags: validation, zend-framework2

I am using Zend Standard Validation Classes (http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.validate.set.html) to validate requests to an api.

You basically specify each request parameter and a set of rules for validating each parameter.

Is it possible to specify that there can be 2 (or more) options when validating a given request, depending on what parameters are in the request?

Like for example if you post:

```
{
    "a": "someVal", 
    "b": "someVal",
    "c": "someVal",
    "d": "someVal"
}
```

then a, b, c, and d are required fields, but if you post like this:

```
{
    "a": "someVal", 
    "e": "someVal",
    "f": "someVal",
    "g": "someVal"
}
```

then a, e, f and g are required fields?

If you examine the data above you will notice that field "b" is a required field in one POST, but it is an optional field in the other POST.

QUESTION:

How do you specify that a request may be validated in 1 of 2 (or more) ways?
How do you specify that a request should be validated based on what parameters are in the request?
Is this possible, and how?

Have been stuck on this one for a while so any assistance would be great..

Zend Framework 2.2

Answer (score 1):

You can create a strategy class that can select input filter that can fit current request based on posted parameters.

In other words your request flow should be something like this:

```
Request -> Route -> Controller -> Input Filter Strategy -> InputFilter -> Other Stuff
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Do you have any sample code for this or a tutorial that I could look into??